# If/Else Logical Flow

Tags: java, if-statement, logic

If I have something like:

```
if (n % 10 == 8 && (n/10) % 10 == 8) count = count + 2;
else if (n % 10 == 8) count++;
```

Basically, if condition `a` and `b` holds, then do something. If only condition `a` holds, do something else. What is the best logical flow for this?

Comment: `if(a) {if(b) something; else something;}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// check the condition a
if (n % 10 == 8)
{
    // check the condition b
    if ((n/10) % 10 == 8))
    {
        count = count + 2;
    }
    // only condition a took place
    else
    {
        count++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the shortest possible code (albeit at the **cost** of readability) you can use the *ternary* op as

```
count += (n % 10) == 8 ? ((n/10) % 10 == 8 ? 2 : 1) : 0;
```